# Can't find variable: Expo

Tags: android, react-native

I am making an app with react native. It has login with facebook option, it keeps giving me this error. "Facebook Login Error: Can't find variable: Expo"
What am I doing wrong here?

Do I have to install some dependencies on Linux

```
f.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if(user){
    //logged in
    console.log('Logged in', user);
  }else {
    //logged out
    console.log('logged out');
  }
});



const { type, token} = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
  'APP_ID',
  { permissions: ['email', 'public_profile'] }
);

if(type === 'success'){
  const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error...',error);
  })
}








Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Expo loginWithFacebook$
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have included Facebook SDK as following

```
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';
```

You shouldn't be redundantly calling Expo.Facbook but instead try

```
const { type, token} = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to import Expo

```
import Expo from 'expo';
```

But you should use expo-facebook module for facebook login for more information please read document here
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/